# Thymeleaf + Spring: 2 objects in form overwrite IDs

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Im using **Spring Boot (v2.0.1.RELEASE)**. Im having the problem in the HTML template, trying to send 2 different objects in a Form to the controller. All attributes form objects are sent successfully except from the ID attribute of both. Both has a field called ID with is being overwriten when arrives to the controller.

Thats the form in the HTML:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/test}" method="post" class="form floating-label">
     <div class="form-group">

          <!-- TEST VARIABLES -->
          <input type="text" th:field="${test.id}" class="form-control"/>
          <input type="text" th:field="${test.nombre}" class="form-control"/>
          <input type="text" th:field="${test.formatotest.id}" class="form-control"/>
          <input type="text" th:field="${test.formatotest.nombre}" class="form-control"/>
          <input type="text" th:field="${test.activo}" class="form-control"/>

          <!-- USER VARIABLES-->
          <input type="text" th:field="${user.id}" class="form-control"/>
          <input type="text" th:field="${user.email}" class="form-control"/>
          <input type="text" th:field="${user.username}" class="form-control"/>

     </div>
     <div>
          <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary btn-raised" />
     </div>
     <br>
</form>
```

Controller Function:

```
@PostMapping("/test")
   public ModelAndView showTest(Test test, User user) {

       System.out.println(" * User ID: ["+user.getId()+"] Test ID:["+test.getId()+"]");

       ModelAndView testModel = new ModelAndView("test");
       testModel.addObject("user",user);
       testModel.addObject("test",test);

       return testModel;
   }
```

When I print both IDs it shows same for both of them. I tried to use th:value, name nad id instead of th:field and it stills fail.

Second try of the HTML form:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/test}" method="post" class="form floating-label">
    <div class="form-group">

         <!-- TEST VARIABLES -->
         <input type="hidden" th:value="${test.id}" name="id" id="id" class="form-control"/>
         <input type="hidden" th:value="${test.nombre}" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="form-control"/>
         <input type="hidden" th:value="${test.formatotest.id}" name="formatotest.id" id="formatotest.id" class="form-control"/>
         <input type="hidden" th:value="${test.formatotest.nombre}" name="formatotest.nombre" id="formatotest.nombre" class="form-control"/>
         <input type="hidden" th:value="${test.activo}" name="activo" id="activo" class="form-control"/>

         <!-- USER VARIABLES-->
         <input type="hidden" th:value="${user.id}" name="id" id="id" class="form-control"/>
         <input type="hidden" th:value="${user.email}" name="email" id="email" class="form-control"/>
         <input type="hidden" th:value="${user.username}" name="username}" id="username" class="form-control"/>

    </div>
    <div>
         <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary btn-raised" />
    </div>
    <br>
</form>
```

A curious detail is that it depends on what input I put first in the HTML that will be the set to both of them.

Comment: What happens when you try to keep th:field but specify different value for name and id attributes ? For example - 
<input type="hidden" th:field="${test.id}" name="testId" id="testId" class="form-control"/>
and
<input type="hidden" th:field="${user.id}" name="userId" id="userId" class="form-control"/>

Comment: I've try it, and it still make the same, it overwrite it. I've read something that when th:field is used, name value and id is ommited and is used when there only one object. I'm really lost...

Comment: In the form, try adding th:object="${test} && ${user}"

Comment: I've tried to add th:object="${test} && ${user}" in form tag like you said and it shows that error. [org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "${test} && ${user}" (template: "index" - line 100, col 67)]. That annotation is not legal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the anwser, not in the clean way it should be but it works fine. As I couldnt send both objects, I created a third object cointaining both ids, and pass those 3 objects to the controller as shown below.

New object containing both ids:

```
package app.TestUser;

import app.hibernate.User;
import app.hibernate.Test;

public class TestUser {

    private String user_id;
    private String test_id;

    public TestUser() {
    }

    public TestUser(String user_id, String test_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.test_id = test_id;
    }

    public String getUser_id() {
        return this.user_id;
    }

    public void setUser_id(String user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    public String getTest_id() {
        return this.test_id;
    }

    public void setTest_id(String test_id) {
        this.test_id = test_id;
    }

}
```

Controller method:

```
public ModelAndView showTest(TestUser testuser, Test test, User user) {

        user.setId(Integer.parseInt(testuser.getUser_id()));
        test.setId(Integer.parseInt(testuser.getTest_id()));

        ModelAndView testModel = new ModelAndView("test");

        testModel.addObject("user",user);
        testModel.addObject("test",test);

        return testModel;
    }
```

HTML Form:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/test}" method="post" class="form floating-label">
     <div class="form-group">

          <!-- TEST VARIABLES -->
          <input type="hidden" th:field="${testuser.test_id}"/>
          <input type="hidden" th:field="${test.nombre}"/>
          <input type="hidden" th:field="${test.formatotest.id}"/>
          <input type="hidden" th:field="${test.formatotest.nombre}"/>
          <input type="hidden" th:field="${test.activo}" name="activo"/>

          <!-- USER VARIABLES-->
          <input type="hidden" th:field="${testuser.user_id}"/>
          <input type="hidden" th:field="${user.email}"/>
          <input type="hidden" th:field="${user.username}"/>

     </div>
     <div>
          <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary btn-raised" />
     </div>
     <br>
</form>
```